# Given a finite group $G$ of order an even number, prove that $G$ contains a non-identity element of order $2$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solution-verification

Given a finite group $G$ of order an even number, prove that $G$ contains a non-identity element of order $2$.

---

**Proof**:

For every non-idenity element $g \in G:g^2 \ne e \iff g \ne g^{-1}$

If such $g$'s exist then the number of them is an even number, since every one of them can be paired with its inverse, follows the number of elements in $G$ that are their own inverse in even, clearly $e=e^{-1}$, so the number of non-identity elements in $G$ that are their own inverse is odd, implies at least $1$ such element does exist.

---

Another way I tried is as follows:

$G$ has an even order iff $\text{ord}(G)=2n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N^+$ iff $ g^{2n} =e$ for $\langle g \rangle = G$ and $e$ the identity element of the given group.Every element is in the group generated by itself and so $g \in \langle g \rangle$,$G$ is a group and so $g^n \in \langle g \rangle$.

On the other hand $(g^n)^2=g^{2n}=e$.

Then I figured out that this just implies that $\text{ord}(g^n)$ divides $2$ and is not necessarily equal to $2$.

Is my conclusion true? besides is it possible to finish the proof using the second way?

Comment: It follows from Cauchy's Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

The second proof is flawed.  For one thing, you seem to assume $G$ is cyclic.

Here is a correct proof:  Partition the elements of $G$ into equivalence classes consisting of $\{g,g^{-1}\}$.  Since the order of $G$ is even, and the identity forms its own equivalence class, there must be an even number $\ge2$ of classes of size $1$.

Another way is by Cauchy's theorem.  A proof of Cauchy's theorem that I like, resembles your second attempt a little.  It uses Sylow's theorems.  Take a Sylow $2$ subgroup.  Then take an element and consider the cyclic group it generates.  The order must be $2^m$, for some $m$.  But any such cyclic group has a subgroup of order $2$.

Comment: Isn't ($2|2n$ then $\exists x\in G$ s.t. $x^2=e$) suffices?

Comment: No. Not if $G$ isn't cyclic. That's why Sylow is needed. @C.F.G.

Comment: Cauchy's theorem states that if $G$ is a finite group and $p$ is a prime number dividing the order of $G$, then $G$ contains an element of order $p$. Now let $p=2$.

Comment: There's an elegant proof of Cauchy's Theorem *sans* Sylow Theorems in Roman's *"Fundamentals of Group Theory: An Advanced Approach"*.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. @Shaun

Comment: You're welcome, @ChrisCuster.

Comment: There you go.  The smallest noncyclic group is the Klein four group, $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$.